# How do frontrunners / sandwich bots work? How do they affect the price in the pool?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, frontrunning, flashbots, mev

I'm trying to understand how frontrunners work in ERC20-Uniswap.

Currently, I don't understand how they can "drain" ETH from a transaction. My understanding is that the price of the pool after the transactions should not be the same as before the transactions, but I observed that they are indeed the same (ie. the bot "drained" the ETH sent to the pool by the innocent trader).

Let's take an example:

[image]

As you can see, the frontrunner bought for 47.760194ETH and sell for 48.693721. So he drained 0.93352668 (huh?) from this unlucky guy (0.98 ETH), but from what I understand, the token pool should have increased by 0.98 ETH... but no, this is not true and this is what I don't understand...

Here is the concept I understand about frontrunners:

Imagine I want to buy an apple with 100$ at 1$/apple, so technically youI will buy 100 apples.
But now, a frontrunner comes and buy apples with 100k$, the price per apple is now much higher (let's take 1 apple = 100$ for the example) he will has 100k apples
Then, after his transaction, i just will buy one apple and increase the price to 120$/apple (example)
Finally, the frontrunner sell 100k apples for 120$ and makes money

From the point of view of the token pool, we will have:
-Frontrunner add 47.76 to the pool
-Unlucky guy add 0.98 to the pool
-Frontrunner makes gains and remove 48.693.. from the pool

So I should still see 0.98 ETH in the pool, right?
Why don't I see them?

Thank you for your help, it's hard for me to explain what I saw!

[image]

Pool size:
[image]

Comment: I do not understand this part in your question : _So I should still see 0.98 ETH in the pool, right? Why don't I see them?_

Comment: Hello @Xavier59, As I said: the frontrunner put 47ETH in the pool with his purchase, then the other person put 0.98ETH and finally the frontrunner sell 48ETH. But if I look at the pool at that time, I should see the remaining 0.98ETH from the guy, right?

Comment: @Xavier59 I added a little image to describe the pool size during this frontrun

Comment: The frontrunner drained 0.93 eth from the pool (48.693 - 47.76) . So if the pool had very low liquidity, it is possible that it allowed the attacker drain almost all of the 0.98 eth from the user.  If the pool size was `n`, the pool size should then be after the attack `n+0.98 - (48.693 - 47.76)`

Comment: This what is don't undestand: how it's possible to "drain" the pool? I mean, when you buy, you put ETH in the pool, and when you sell, you take ETH from the pool. How is it possible to drain?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR Sandwich bots work by having a buy transaction before the victim's buy transaction, then a sell transaction just after. They profit from the increase of price caused by the victim's buy transaction in the middle.**

When you send a swap transaction to a DEX like Uniswap/Pancakeswap, you must also specify a slippage tolerance (in %). It is like saying "I want to buy 1 apple for 100$, but I am ok if, when the transaction is processed, the price is up to 102$ and I want the transaction to go through anyway." The bot exploit this slippage tolerance for profit.

**Here is a very (very) simplified example:**

1. The bot will first buy the apple at 100$ for an amount that will
   raise the price to 101$. The bot now has 1 apple paid 100$.
2. The victim buys 1 apple. The victim wanted to pay 100$, but is still ok with a price of 101$ (slippage tolerance), so the transaction goes through. This purchase raises the price to 102$ after the transaction is processed.
3. The bot sells its apple at the current price of 102$ for a 2$ profit. The price goes back down to 101$ after the transaction.

Basically, sandwich bots are extracting the slippage tolerance of traders.

**What about the price discrepancy?**

Your question seems to imply that the price reverts back to the original 100$ following those transactions. I don't think that it is the case. The net effect should be that the price of apples will rise because of the victim's transaction. Otherwise, the constant product formula (x*y=k) would not be upheld. If you saw the price revert back to 100$, it was most likely because of an arbitrage transaction somewhere else in the block, not the sandwich bot (but that is a subject for another day).